# Retrieving place description from google places API

Tags: android, google-places-api

[image]

Is there any way to retrieve this?...summary of a place using google places API or any other API.
Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: did you manage to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, if you use the SDK of **Places** for android you can retrieve the details of a place. See the [docs](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/place-details?hl=pt-br). More specifically , to retrieve the info you highlighted you can use `getAttributions()`, see [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place.html?hl=pt-br#getAttributions()).